# Pytest-html plugin report, list deselected tests

Tags: pytest-html

Is there a way to include deselected tests in the pytest generated html report, similarly to skipped tests?

- generated html file: file:///*/*/*/*/*/*/reports/report.html -
  ================ 13 passed, 41 skipped, 6 deselected in 35.54s =================

I found a solution to have them printed in the terminal by adding this to **conftest.py**

```
def pytest_deselected(items):
    if not items:
        return
    config = items[0].session.config
    reporter = config.pluginmanager.getplugin("terminalreporter")
    reporter.ensure_newline()
    for item in items:
        reporter.line(f"deselected: {item.nodeid}", yellow=True, bold=True)
```

but can't figure out how to get these tests listed in the report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up marking them as skipped instead of deselecting them, that way they are easily listed on the report.